# Add onclick event to hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a string containing my html content in code behind link like this:

```
<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">rrr</a></p>"
```

1. I need to add a `onclick` event to this link.
2. Need to get the href value.

I don't have a id or class for the link so can't access it directly using JavaScript. I am new to jQuery. Kind of stuck here. How can I achieve this?

I tried using the JavaScript `onclick solutions` by preventing default functionality, but MY HTML CONTENT IS GENERATED AT RUNTIME. So whatever I write in `document.ready` doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: You have to provide more of your html but if you want to get first of href use `jQuery('p a:first')` or last `jQuery('p a:last')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery with working jsbin - http://jsbin.com/azOSayA/1/edit

```
$("a").click(function(e){
 var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: On your jsbin the value logged is the html enclosed in the a tag, not the href attribute. Does it have anything to do with the backslashes in the attribute ?

Comment: @Lapidouce : thanks for noticing me.. i have updated bin

Comment: `$('a').attr('href');` will not give you the `current anchor tag href`, you should use `$(this).attr('href');` here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('p a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('href'));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/ncHaQ/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("p a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $("p a").click(
      function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).attr("href"); //do something with this
      }
 );
```

This will add a onclick listener to every link within the page which is a child of a paragraph.

If the link is really important, you should probably give it an id, so that it can be identified uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("p a").on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   alert(link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Nyrsu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p").find("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href= $(this).prop("href");
  });
});
```