# CSS Styled button won't work?

Tags: html, css

Granted, I styled it in [CSS Button Generator](http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/) , because I'm lazy and terrible at CSS anyway, but it was working before my awful attempt at pasting the code!

So, for context, I have decided to add my entire code on a pastebin link, sorry if it's too much of a hassle. [Click here.](http://pastebin.com/rwQh0UcM)

I can't get it to work, however, if the fancy CSS Style is shown, the button won't work. If the button works, it's in the hyperlinked version. Help?

Comment: It is inside a <script></script> tag! I didn't post my whole code because it could be a pain, if necessary, I'll include a pastebin link!

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm a newbie myself, as far I know `document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function()` has to be kept in  script tag

Like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function()
</script>
```

Check if that worked

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Hyperlinks wont work as buttons despite the fact it can be styled to look like one

My suggestion would be to style a button in the sense you tried to style the hyperlink

A simple debugging method testing weather hyperlinks can act as buttons would be adding onclick to the hyperlink

This question was closed but has an accepted answer I feel may benefit you
[Add onclick event to hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308477/add-onclick-event-to-hyperlink)

Comment: No, no. It's not really an hyperlink. I'm just terrible at explaining myself. I'll include a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rwQh0UcM) link for reference.

Comment: anything that uses the <a tag is a HYPERLINK your code is not working bc javascript does not work well with hyperlinks due to the fact hyperlinks are used for navigation

Answer (score 0):

This works.. Copy following code ant try it

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){alert();})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myButton" id="myButton">green</a>

<style>
.myButton {
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:28px;
 -webkit-border-radius:28px;
 border-radius:28px;
 border:1px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:17px;
 padding:16px 31px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
</style>
```